# How to dynamically change the context to display last year value when using any date slicer (like: Yr, YrQtr, YrMon, YrWk)?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

My calendar table has columns for:

```
Date
Year
Qtr
Month
Week
Yr qtr
Yr month
Yr week
Yr week (start date)
Yr week (end date)
```

Plus there are few sort columns.

Product dimension has columns like pid, Product, Category.

The fact table has various fields, important to this question is: SalesAmt

This model is available to end users to create their own reports.

My task is to create a measure showing Sales this year and Sales last year.

I have created following measures:

```
Total Sales = SUM(FACTSALES[SALESAMT])

Total Sales LY =
var LY = MAX(CALENDAR[YR])
CALCULATE([Total Sales], YR = LY - 1)
```

To test this, on the report I have added slicers for Yr, YrQtr, YrMon, YrWk.

The table visual has Product in the rows, and the above 2 measures as values.

When I choose Yr slicer as 2024, then this works correctly.

But if I choose any other slicer, then I don't get any value for the LY measure. I understand this is because for example when I choose Yr Qtr value as Y24 Q1, then this sticks to the filter context of the LY measure.

What is the correct way to handle this? In above example when user selects Y24 Q1, then it should show value for Y23 Q1.

If user select Y24 W3, then it should show value for Y23 W3.

If user select Y24 M5, then it should show value for Y23 W5.

Answer (score 0):

Leverage the DAX [Time intelligence functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax). For example:

```
Total Sales LY = CALCULATE( [Total Sales], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(CALENDAR[Date]) )
```

Specifically for getting last year's weeks by week number (if they shift) then you could have:

```
Total Sales LY (by weekNum) = 
  var thisYear = MAX(CALENDAR[YR])
  var thisWeeks = DISTINCT( CALENDAR[WEEK] )
  return
    CALCULATE(
      [Total Sales],
      REMOVEFILTERS(CALENDAR), // or ALL(CALENDAR)
      CALENDAR[YR] = thisYear - 1 &&
      CALENDAR[WEEK] IN thisWeeks
    )
```

Comment: I tried this but it does calculation based on dates. Where as I want to do it based on weeks last year. Is this possible?

Comment: If your calendar table is setup correctly then it should work. Week X in this year = a range of dates, which will translate to the same period of last year, and in turn should match the week X of the previous year. Or do your week numbers shift in terms of dates?

Comment: Updated answer for week calculation - if that helps.

Comment: I assume DISTINCT can also be replaced with VALUES?

Comment: Correct. `DISTINCT` doesn't return a blank value, whereas `VALUES` may do. [Difference between DISTINCT and VALUES in DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2011/03/08/difference-between-distinct-and-values-in-dax/)